# Getting correct result with Group By query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
with CTE as 
(
  select Barkod, sum(kolicina) as Kolicina 
  from stocks
  where Barkod = '555'
  group by Barkod
)
select s.Barkod, s.Kategorija, s.Artikal, s.Opis, s.Kolicina, s.N_cena,
  s.N_Iznos, s.P_cena, s.P_Iznos, s.datum, s.Golemina from Stocks as s
join CTE as b 
  on b.Barkod = s.Barkod
```

The results from this query is

```
555 КОШУЛА      QWRSF    QWRSF    10    10.00   NULL   20.00   NULL    NULL  NULL
555 КОШУЛА      QWRSF    QWRSF     1    10.00   NULL   20.00   NULL    NULL  NULL
```

I need to get the following result

```
555 КОШУЛА      QWRSF    QWRSF    11    10.00   NULL   20.00   NULL    NULL  NULL
```

So I need to sum up the Kolicina field and get all in one row.

Comment: i think that should be (select b...) instead select (s...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close...just one last grouping.

```
select s.Barkod, s.Kategorija, s.Artikal, s.Opis, sum(s.Kolicina), s.N_cena,
s.N_Iznos, s.P_cena, s.P_Iznos, s.datum, s.Golemina from Stocks as s
group by s.Barkod, s.Kategorija, s.Artikal, s.Opis,  s.N_cena,
s.N_Iznos, s.P_cena, s.P_Iznos, s.datum, s.Golemina
```

Any other lines you may want summed can be moved out of the group by and have the sum() put onto it in the select line.

Comment: If you get rid of the join and the CTE, surely that will still work as a standalone query.

Comment: Laurence is right...this is a rather redundant statement with the CTE declare (it'll work, the join to B is kinda pointless).  Skip the CTE declare and join and it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find some way to aggregate the other columns.

e.g.

```
select
    Barkod, 
    sum(kolicina) as Kolicina, 
    Max(Kategorija) as Kategorija,
    Max(Artikal) as Artikal, 
    Max(Opis) as Opis, 
    Max(N_cena) as N_cena,
    Max(N_Iznos) as N_Iznos, 
    Max(P_cena) as P_cena, 
    Max(P_Iznos) as P_Iznos, 
    Max(datum) as datum, 
    Max(Golemina) as Golemina
from 
    stocks
where 
    Barkod = '555'
group by 
    Barkod
```

This pattern would tend to suggest your data isn't properly normalized, though.

Alternatively, if the non-summed columns always have identical values for the Barkod, you can just do:

```
select
    Barkod, 
    sum(kolicina) as Kolicina, 
    Kategorija,
    Artikal,
    Opis,
    N_cena,
    N_Iznos,
    P_cena,
    P_Iznos,
    datum,
    Golemina
from 
    stocks
where 
    Barkod = '555'
group by 
    Barkod,
    Kategorija,
    Artikal,
    Opis,
    N_cena,
    N_Iznos,
    P_cena,
    P_Iznos,
    datum,
    Golemina
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `..., s.Kolicina, ...` for `..., b.Kolicina, ...` to get the `SUM` from the `table b`. The way you're doing, you're just selecting all `Kolicina` from `table s`.